# How to query if VueJs /Vuetify is currently animating?

Tags: selenium, vue.js, selenium-webdriver, vuetify.js

For Angular and Jquery it is possible to check if something on the page is currently animating. For example I can just use the css selector ".ng-animating" to check if any elements have the animating class on them.

We use this a lot for our end 2 end test automation, for example to only assert if elements are displayed on the page after the user has done some action. We will just wait untill no elements have the ".ng-animating class".

We started using Vue for a few new projects and I am trying to also find out if it is possible so query some attribute, or set some event when it start to animate and finishes the animations. Does somebody know how to? Or have a different approach which will also work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Custom-Transition-Classes) there are 6 classes for animation

```
enter-class
enter-active-class
enter-to-class (2.1.8+)
leave-class
leave-active-class
leave-to-class (2.1.8+)
```

Perhaps you can use a pair of them.

Comment: Yes, this worked! Made a selector like this to check if something had these class names: document.querySelector(
       "[class$=-enter], [class$=-enter-to], [class$=-enter-active], [class$=-leave],class$=-leave-to], [class$=-leave-active]"  );

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with applications built with [Angular](https://angular.io/) and/or [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), to query the *class* attribute **ng-animating** you can induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following [java](/questions/tagged/java) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- When it starts to animations use *ExpectedConditions* as [visibilityOfElementLocated()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-):

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".ng-animating")));
  ```
- When it finishes the animations use *ExpectedConditions* as [invisibilityOfElementLocated()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-):

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".ng-animating")));
  ```

Comment: This is how you implement it when you finally have the selector. As stated in my first sentence I was already aware how to do it for jquery or angular. VueJs was being a bore. Thank your for the reaction.